# Jumping in Unity by AddForce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm recently started working with physics in Unity and I need to let my character jump.
I want to do it by `AddForce()` but I also need to check is the character grounded.
In the code I'm checking it with time.
Here is my code:

```
private void JumpByForce() 
{
    time_after_jump = Time.time + 1f;
    Debug.Log(time_after_jump);

    if (Time.time > time_after_jump)
    {
        isJumping = true;
    }
    if (isJumping)
    {
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 750));
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    Player_pos_x = Player.transform.position.x;
    Player_pos_y = Player.transform.position.y;
    isJumping = true;
    
}
```

I thought that I wrote a right code, but in `console` isn't appearing what I want.
(It's printing `time_after_jump` without adding `+ 1f`).
At the first time when I'm clicking on the jump button the Player Jumping correctly.But the following times it isn't jumping.
My biggest question Is - Why `time_after_jump` printing without
(`+ 1f`)?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call 'JumpByForce()' method?

Comment: If you adding 1f to the time, and assigning that to time_after_jump, then it will be showing that in the Debug, just with the 1f already applied. I.E, b = 2; a = b + 1. The debug would show as 3, not a + 1 (or 2+ 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Debug.Log()` prints the final value, not the expression in the variable. In your situation, it prints the final value of `time_after_jump`. Unity calculates that value on the previous line and then prints it (So instead of printing 10+1 it prints 11).

Also, the reason your player doesn't jump after the first time is because `Time.time` will never be greater than `time_after_jump` since you are adding 1 to it before the check, therefore the first if is never triggered, and therefore `isJumping` is never true apart from the first time when you initialize it with the value true.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. I need to save final value of this expression(`time_after_jump = Time.time + 1f;`), and check if `Time.time` is more than `time_after_jump`

Comment: @Hayk `Time.time` will never be greater than `time_after_jump` because you give it a higher value before the check.

Comment: If I'm giving to `time_after_jump` `Time.time + 1f` expression AT ONCE and `Time.time` keeps adding his value, Why is it will never be more than `time_after_jump`?

Comment: Because that function is not running on Update (and even if it did it wouldn't work because with every call time_after_jump is initialized to be bigger than Time.time.
Also, Time.time is not adding to his value, you are just getting the current time from it.

Comment: Thanks for a careful explanation. I've solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the problem here. `if(Time.time > time_after_jump)` while always return `false`.

Let's say Time.time = 2. And time_after_jump = Time.time + 1. Then time_after_jump = 3. Meaning it is always greater.

Try this instead:

```
time_after_jump = Time.time;
Debug.Log(time_after_jump);

if ((Time.time + 1f) > time_after_jump)
{
    isJumping = true;
}
```

Although, personally I would use time.deltaTime, create a timer, and reset the timer value when jumping, so as to set isJumping to false.

E.g:

```
time_after_jump += Time.deltaTime; 
if(time_after_jump > timeJumping)
{
  isJumping = true;
}

if(isJumping)
{
   //Movement here
   time_after_jump = 0;
   isJumping = false;
}
```

However, this would be a lot simpler if you used an Input to get the jump. Then you would reset the timer when jump is pressed.

Am at work, so this is untested, but I hope you get the idea. Happy coding.

Comment: In your example you mentioned it correctly but in `time_after_jump` I need to save a constant value and then check if `Time.time` higher than `time_after_jump`. `time_after_jum` saving value of `Time.time`(for example 2) and then adding 1f to that value(summary `time_after_jump` keeping 3f) but `Time.time` isn't constant It'll raise until it will be higher than `time_after_jump`. And as I anderstood `time_after_time` saving this value single time when I'm clicking on button that activates `JumpByForce()` function.

Comment: That's why I would add to the variable (+=) instead of assigning (=), that way you can reset the variable to 0. Time.time will keep increasing during the  gameplay. The way it is set up, you would have to minus from time_after_jump after every jump, but if the function is getting called from an Update it will constantly be setting the time_after_jump to Time.time, which + 1 will always be greater, and is_jumping will always be true.

Comment: The function calls from pressing on button and I don't need to make 0 `time_after_jump`'s variable. Anyways I'm getting value of `Time.time` and adding him `1f` whatever `Time.time` will be

Answer (score 0):

To make the character jump by AddForce with time I've must check `time_after_jump` in `FixedUpdate` method and if `Time.time` will more than `time_after_jump`, than `isJumping` will be true and I can again jump our character.

I used this code:

```
private void JumpByForce() 
{
    if (isJumping)
    {
        time_after_jump = Time.time + 0.8f;
        Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 750));
        isJumping = false;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Time.time > time_after_jump)
    {
        isJumping = true;
    }
}
```